# How to POST an empty ForeignKey field in Django?

Tags: python, django, view

I'm fairly new to this. I have an app that is basically a check in/check out form. The form has 3 fields, two of which are required and one that is optional. One of the required fields in an "Area" and the only field that is not required is the "Station" because not every area has a station, so sometimes there will be no option to choose from station. It currently works fine if you fill out all 3 fields, but not if the station is empty, even if the area doesn't have a station.

I get this error: 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in my views.py, in one of my if statements for both the enter/leave because it happens on both actions, but I'm not sure what exactly it could be. The point of those if statements is that:

If a person entered an area and forgot to leave and then entered another area, the program would create a new entry and not touch the previous area entry after the person leaves the new area (a person can enter and leave same area/station multiple times), so when they leave the most recent entry would be the only one modified. It's a similar concept for leave area, and a lot of the filters I added is so that previous entries are not modified due to .update() being a mass update for everything that was left after filter, not only the most recent.

**models.py**

```
class WorkArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class StationNumber(models.Model):
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(models.Model):
    employee_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, help_text="Employee #", blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Time in", null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, help_text="Time out", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['station_number'].queryset = StationNumber.objects.none()

        if 'work_area' in self.data:
            try:
                work_area_id = int(self.data.get('work_area'))
                self.fields['station_number'].queryset = StationNumber.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['station_number'].queryset = self.instance.work_area.stations.order_by('name')
```

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = self.request.POST['employee_number']
        area = self.request.POST['work_area']
        station = self.request.POST['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            if EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)).filter(Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number__isnull=True)):
                EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)).update(time_in=datetime.now())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        elif 'leave_area' in self.request.POST:
            if EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_out__isnull=True):
                recent = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_out__isnull=True).latest('time_in').time_in
                EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station, time_out__isnull=True, time_in=recent).update(time_out=datetime.now())
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

            form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(employee_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station).update(time_out=datetime.now())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)


def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = StationNumber.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
Internal Server Error: /operations/enter-exit-area/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\apps.rsrgroup.com\apps\operations\views.py", line 24, in form_valid
    if EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)).filter(Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number=None)):
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1281, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\mkusneco\appsve\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
[25/Oct/2019 11:21:47] "POST /operations/enter-exit-area/ HTTP/1.1" 500 172567
```

Comment: I expect the call to `filter(...`station_number=station`...)` is the issue, though it would help if you gave more of the traceback.  It is expecting a `StationNumber` class and trying to get its primary key id but you are passing in `station = self.request.POST['station_number']`, which is a string or a number but probably not a `StationNumber` instance and may be None.

Comment: @FiddleStix Just added traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form, but you're ignoring it. The form will helpfully convert all the raw posted data to the relevant types, in particular it will convert the integer ID you get for `station_number` into an actual instance of StationNumber. But, you are not using the form's cleaned_data; instead you go back to the raw POST. Don't do that.

It should be:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']
        ...
```